# How redshifted galaxies will JWST be able to detect?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, space-telescope, noise

I see that the [MIRI](https://webb.nasa.gov/content/observatory/instruments/miri.html) camera/spectrograph on JWST has an operational wavelength span between 5 and 28 micrometers. Now visible not redshifted light has wavelengths between 400 and 700 nanometers. If this was the limiting factor JWST would be able to detect light from galaxies far away in a distant passed that is redshifted about 28/0.7 = 40 times (z=39).

I see that the [Lyman series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series) for hydrogen spectra has one peak at 1026 nanometers and one at 1216 if these are somehow needed to determine the redshift of a distant galaxy JWST would still be able to detect galaxies at a redshift of 28/1.216 = 23 times (z=22).

As I understand things these are not limiting factors but instead the temperature of the satellite itself producing blackbody radiation at the same wavelengths the satellite is observing in creating noise that can drown the signal.

Now that JWST is operational, what can be said of the theoretical limits for how much redshifted galaxies the telescope will be able to detect and determine the redshift of?

If an identical copy of the Milky Way was residing far out in space, what is the redshift limit for us being able to detect it with JWST?

If there are more luminous galaxies out there, say a galaxy with four time the intrinsic luminosity of the Milky Way, at what maximal redshift will we be able to detect it?

How much of a role does exposure time play?

I see that later this fall JWST is going to to a 60 hour exposure of the same part of the sky that Hubble observed in the "Ultra deep field".

Are there other limiting factors such as heat radiation from nearby cold hydrogen gas?

**Question**: At what maximal redshifts will JWST be able to detect galaxies and determine their redshifts and to what extent does the intrinsic luminosites of galaxies and exposure time matter?

Comment: This is a really interesting question but I don't think that the cosmological capability of the space telescope is a good fit for Space Exploration SE. I've upvoted and also voted to close so that migration to Astronomy SE will be possible, where it can join your other cosmological capability questions about JWST.